# Android upload multi files to server via http post

Tags: android, http, post

I need to upload file from Android client to an URL via HTTP POST.
If upload just 1 file, than it is OK for me. but my target URL page code is looks like following

```html
<form action="file_upload.php" enctype ="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile">
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile2">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

How can I upload 2 more files via HTTP POST at same time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried following code and confirm that's workable solution:

```
StringBuffer responseBody=new StringBuffer();

Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Ready to upload file...");
HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Set remote URL...");
HttpPost post=new HttpPost("http://IP.IP.IP.IP/file_upload.php");
MultipartEntity entity=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Adding file(s)...");
entity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody((FileObj), "application/zip"));
entity.addPart("uploadedfile2", new FileBody((FileObj), "application/zip"));

Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Set entity...");
post.setEntity(entity);

BufferedReader bs=null;
try
{
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Upload...");
  HttpEntity hEntity=client.execute(post).getEntity();
  bs=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(hEntity.getContent()));
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Response length - "+hEntity.getContentLength());
  String s="";
  while(s!=null)
  {
    responseBody.append(s);
    s=bs.readLine();
    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Response body - "+s);
  }
  bs.close();
}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
  Log.i(Constants.TAG, "Error on getting response from Server, "+ioe.toString());
  ioe.printStackTrace();
  responseBody.append("...");
}
```

My platform is Android 2.2, and use this solution need to get httpmime.jar as project library.

Comment: If you need to add any arguments in request, then add in MultiPartEntity object such as<br> multiPartEntity.addPart("testpara,", new StringBody("value"));<br>

Comment: @AnkitRox bro tell me something! Where did u got <br> syntax in java?