# Android HttpPost with Gzip and NameValuePair

Tags: android, http, gzip

Is it possible to set 2 entities for a HttpPost? Like:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.abc.com");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("A",
                a));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("B", b));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

post.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

ByteArrayEntity bae = new ByteArrayEntity(compress(json));

post.setEntity(bae);
HttpResponse resp;
resp = client.execute(post);
```

I'm trying to achieve telling the server that there are some parameters and a zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes You can send zip file and pass parameter using nameValuePairs. go to below link you may get your solution.

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/

[Android upload multi files to server via http post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728689/android-upload-multi-files-to-server-via-http-post)

in this link place your zip file address on place of image. and you may have to do some more modification.

Comment: The links were really useful in achieving what I needed with a little tweaking, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not like this. You need use a multi-part entity, you can manually encode it if it is relatively simple, or use org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity (which is not part of the Android SDK). There are multiple post about it on SO, search for 'android multipart'.