# Uploading image multi part form from android

Tags: android, multipartform-data

i have this problem that i want to upload image on a server through multi-part form but its keep giving me invalid image when i try to upload it from android but work fine from web.
this is html form which work fine.

http://letitripple.org/htmlForm.html

this is the request this html form create. (i get from chrome developer tool)

------WebKitFormBoundaryPug6xAUAlaUPbR86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wp-user-avatars"; filename="Desert.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryPug6xAUAlaUPbR86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login_id"

51
------WebKitFormBoundaryPug6xAUAlaUPbR86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cookie"

ali.asim@gmail.com|1473394633|vcN3CTbKi6pkAjPMKH1D9MHucPLKhw3wyeS7ViSTgGb|f5cbd913f6c3d6940066a660bac5908adb016682ce34f48e8200773eb4503c1e
------WebKitFormBoundaryPug6xAUAlaUPbR86
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

submit
------WebKitFormBoundaryPug6xAUAlaUPbR86--

This is my android code which is not working.

```
 public AppResponse uploadImageFile(String csURL, String csFilePath)
{
    AppResponse appResponse = null;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
    InputStream inStream = null;


    String Url = csURL;
    String existingFileName = csFilePath;


    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "WebKitFormBoundaryleA9RIQsQBxW8Cgl";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
 //   String reponse_data = null;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  //  String urlString = "YOUR PHP LINK FOR UPLOADING IMAGE";
    try {
        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
        // FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName) );
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        URL url = new URL(Url);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
        byte[] bytes;
        byte[] buffers = new byte[605244];
        int bytesReads;
        output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + twoHyphens + twoHyphens + boundary);
        //conn.setRequestProperty("attach1", existingFileName);
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + twoHyphens + twoHyphens + boundary + "\r\n");



        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attach1\"; filename=\"profile.jpg\"\n Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n\r\n"); // uploaded_file_name is the Name of the File to be uploaded

        // create a buffer of  maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0) {

            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            Log.e("Value", "Writing");

        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + twoHyphens + twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens);

        //String strInput = dos.toString();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();


        fileInputStream.close();

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        int nResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));

        String line = "";
        StringBuilder csResult = new StringBuilder("");

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + csResult);
            csResult.append(line);
        }


        appResponse = new AppResponse(nResponseCode, csResult.toString());



    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }


    return appResponse;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if [my case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728689/android-upload-multi-files-to-server-via-http-post) would help... FYR